# When I read excel data. Some cells have incomplete data

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C#.
When I execute the following code.
Some cells have incomplete data.
This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace PracFileCreater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "test.xlsx";

            int sheetNum = 1;
            string columnName = "E";
            int startRow = 6;
            int endRow = 39;

            Application app = new Application();
            List<string> pracNameList = ReadWorksheetColumn(app, filePath, sheetNum, columnName, startRow, endRow);
            foreach (string name in pracNameList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
            app.Quit();
        }

        static List<string> ReadWorksheetColumn(Application app, string path, int sheetNum, string columnName, int startRow, int endRow)
        {
            List<string> pracNameList = new List<string>();

            Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetNum];
            Range pracNameRange = worksheet.Range[columnName + startRow.ToString() + ":" + columnName + endRow.ToString()];
            
            foreach (Range cell in pracNameRange.Cells)
            {
                string value = cell.Value?.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    pracNameList.Add(value);
                }
            }

            workbook.Close(false);

            return pracNameList;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the result of the code execution.

```
演習1-1
演習2-1
演習2-2
演習3-1
演習3-2
演習3-3
演習4-1
演習4-2
演習4-3
演習4-3
演習4-4
演習4-5
演習5-1
演習5-2
演習5-3
演習5-4
演習6-1
演習6-2
演習6-3
演習7-1
演習7-2
演習7-3
演習7-4
演習7-5
演習7-6
演習7-7
演習8-1
演習8-2
演習8-3
演習8-4
演習9-1
```

This is the original excel data.

```
演習1-1
演習2-1
演習2-2
演習3-1
演習3-2
演習3-3
演習4-1
演習4-2
演習4-3f
演習4-3w
演習4-4
演習4-5
演習5-1
演習5-2
演習5-3
演習5-4
演習6-1
演習6-2
演習6-3
演習7-1
演習7-2
演習7-3
演習7-4
演習7-5
演習7-6
演習7-7
演習8-1
演習8-2
演習8-3
演習8-4
演習9-1
```

The result is that 演習4-3f has been changed to 演習4-3 and the data f is lost. How to fix this problem.

Comment: Did you forget to save the spreadsheet?

Comment: I read the data after I saved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get it working fine using the below. Can you try this?

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> pracNameList = new List<string>();
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;

        using ExcelPackage xlPackage = new(new FileInfo(@"C:\Projects\book1.xlsx"));
        var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        var totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
        var totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

        var pracNameRange = worksheet.SelectedRange["E" + "1" + ":" + "E" + "31"];

        foreach (var cell in pracNameRange)
        {
            string value = cell.Value.ToString();
            pracNameList.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

[procNameList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trzUp.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use your code. But It also loss data.

Comment: Ok. I have the wrong worksheet number. I change 0 to 1.Now it's working properly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified code.

```
static List<string> ReadWorksheetColumn(string path, int sheetNum, string columnName, int startRow, int endRow)
{
    List<string> pracNameList = new List<string>();

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    ExcelWorkbook wb = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo).Workbook;
    var worksheet = wb.Worksheets[sheetNum];

    var pracNameRange = worksheet.SelectedRange[columnName + startRow + ":" + columnName + endRow];
    foreach (var cell in pracNameRange)
    {
        var value = cell.Value?.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            pracNameList.Add(value);
        }
    }

    return pracNameList;
}
```